# Python abre fichero .py pero no un .txt del mismo directorio

Tags: python, archivo, txt

Estoy iniciándome en Python y ya estoy empezando con los ficheros.

En la misma carpeta (C:\Users\Paco\Python\Varios) tengo los ficheros Files_Operations.py, que es el que estoy ejecutando y también tzop.txt que es el fichero que intento abrir.

El fichero Files_Operations.py tiene estas dos líneas:

```
st=open("tzop.txt", "rt", encoding="utf-8")
print (st.read())
```

Al ejecutarlo me da la excepción errno 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paco\Python\Varios\Files_Operations.py", line 1,
    st=open("tzop.txt", "rt", encoding="utf-8")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tzop.txt'
```

Si cambio el nombre del fichero por "Sudoku.py" que está en la misma carpeta, lo abre correctamente.

He intentado ponerle al fichero .txt delante "./" y la ruta completa "C:/Users/Paco/Python/Varios/tzop.txt" pero el resultado es el mismo. También he probado a ponerle mode="r" pero igual.

Gracias de antemano por vuestro interés.

Comment: Tu código funciona (lo acabo de probar), vuelve a mirar que este bien escrito el nombre del .txt o que no le hayas puesto por error 2 veces la extension `.txt.txt`.
Mira este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282935/10540710

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta DaniDekk, era eso lo que pasaba. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como es la opción correcta, si respondes a la pregunta la podré cerrar como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona (lo acabo de probar), vuelve a mirar que este bien escrito el nombre del fichero de texto o que no le hayas puesto por error 2 veces la extension `.txt.txt`

Mira este enlace por si te ayuda: [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282935/10540710)

Answer (score 0):

La ruta es correcta pero el orden de los parámetros puede que no. La manera correcta es la siguiente:

open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

El encoding es el 4to parámetro y puede que eso te este afectando. Intenta no pásarle y codificarlo luego o pasar el 3er parámetro como -1.

Comment: Persiste el error con las opciones que me indicas. No creo que sea cuestión de parámetros porque el fichero .py lo abre correctamente. El problema se reduce a gestionar el fichero .txt. La misma orden, con los mismos parámetros abre Sudoku.py pero da error con tzop.txt